# Is the function $f(w) = e^{-w}w^{z-1}$ holomorphic for $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Is the function $f(w) = e^{-w}w^{z-1}$ holomorphic for $z \in \mathbb{C}$? I'm confused on how I could go at proving this as there is a complex number in the exponent.

Is this even valid for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ or are there points where this does not hold?

Comment: What have you tried? You might find it helpful to note that that $w^{z-1} = (e^{\ln(w)})^{z-1}$ for any choice of $\ln(w)$.

Comment: @AlexNolte I thought about that, but I'm still new (and quite confused) to the logarithm in $\mathbb{C}$ with the branch and everything. I actually want to use this result to prove the Mellin transformation of cosine, but I got stuck on this (quite trivial?) part...

Comment: @AlexNolte in most proofs of the Mellin transformation, they just start by saying that the function is analytic, but I wanted to verify this.

Comment: This is locally analytic for a continuous choice of $\ln(w)$, and the only concern is that $\ln(w)$ is only defined up to addition of $2\pi i n$. The worry here is that if we try to make a continuous choice of $\ln(w)$ around the unit circle, our choice of $\ln(w)$ changes by $2\pi i$. To avoid this requires that the function be invariant under adding $2\pi i n$ to $\ln(w)$, which implies that $z$ is an integer.

Comment: @AlexNolte So $z$ can only be an integer? That doesn't sound right...

Comment: The function is analytic for any $z$! It just cannot be defined holomorphically on all of $\mathbb{C}$ for any $z$; it seems one needs to make a branch cut unless $z$ is an integer.

Comment: @AlexNolte ok then I should've rephrased my question: how can I prove that this function is analytic? I know the $e$-power is by definition but the complex exponent got me confused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131998/discussion-between-alex-nolte-and-geigercounter).

Comment: You supplied some context in your Comments, but this would be better included in the body of your Question so that Readers better understand where you successfully digested the problem and where your insight fails.  The general ill-defined nature of complex numbers to complex powers has been discussed in numerous previous Questions, so your interest in the Mellin transform helps to set your Question apart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we choose a branch of the natural log and write $w = e^{\ln(w)}$ then where $\ln(w)$ is continuously defined we can express $f(w) = \exp(-w + \ln(w)(z-1)),$ which is the composition and product of holomorphic functions and hence holomorphic. This can be done on the complement of any closed ray $r e^{i\theta}$ for $\theta$ fixed and $r \geq 0$.

This is not extendable to the entire complex plane unless $z$ is an integer (in which case, choosing different definitions of $\ln(w)$ corresponds to multiplication by $2n\pi i = 1$). For instance, with $z = 1/2$, we have a factor of $\sqrt{w}$, which cannot be defined on the whole complex plane continuously. One should also be careful that our function depends on the choice of branch of $\ln(w)$.